# Detect if Tabulator table data has changed to propmt the user to save the data?

Tags: tabulator

I have a table where data is stored in a text file. There is a button to save the data back to the text file. If the user leaves the page any unsaved data is lost.

Is there a method to detect if the table data has changed? I could then give the user the option to save or leave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a ***dataEdited*** callback that is called when data in the table has been edited:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    dataEdited:function(data){
    //data - the updated table data
    },
});
```

You could use this to set a boolean elsewhere that can be checked when the user tries to leave the page.

Have a look at the [Callbacks Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/callbacks) for more information on the wide range of callbacks that Tabulator offers

Comment: Missed that callback. Works perfectly.